# Getting mysqli_fetch_array data without 'moving' to next row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, row

I have a result from a complicated sql query. The result is something like this:

```
player_id   mail_text   mail_title
1           hello       talking
2           hi          talking
1           how are u?  talking
2           fine!       talking
```

**Now, I want to scan through all the result using `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)` and show the result in table rows, BUT BEFORE the loop I want to output the mail_title.**

I don't want to use `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` to show the title, because then the loop will start from 2nd row and not from the 1st row.

Also I don't want to do a double query because the query is too large.

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: You have to learn to use templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

a) suck the entire result set into a client-side buffer, e.g.

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

And then extract your title from that array.

b) `seek` back to the beginning on your result set, using [mysqli::data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php). Not all result sets are seekable, however.

Comment: Second is not an option at all, **especaiily** because you should never do no output while fetching data from table.

Comment: yea i've thought about using javascript to update the title after the query but it feels wrong to me. any other option?

Comment: put some logic into your fetch loop `if (on_first_row()) { output title }`

Comment: @YourCommonSense: show me where the law says you can't NOT do output while fetching...

Comment: i liked on_first_row() stuff. that function exists? if no how do i make a first-row condition?

Comment: no, it doesn't exist. that's something you'll have to do yourself. e.g. `$first = true; while(...) { If ($first) { show_title(); $first = false;}}`

Answer (score -1):

Do a simple count.  If you're on the first row, then fetch/output your title.

```
$data = array();
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ( $i == 1 ) {
        // do stuff
    }
    $data[] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Count is overkill here.